# Automatic simulation using pspice

Tags: pspice

I should consider many specific values for a circuit's parameters and simulate the circuit in each case by PSpice to get output files. Because of high number of required simulation, I am searching a way to automate this process. Would you please help me?

Comment: UTFG parametric analysis. Or statistical analysis in case there is greater number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The term is "parametric analysis". There are many examples online, or you can just look at the [manual here](http://www-3.unipv.it/ele1/pspice/pspice91/pspice.pdf) in Chapter 11.